# Getting Bad Request (400) on Azure Notification Hub's "Test Send"

Tags: android, azure, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to send the following payload to a specific device (which is why I'm using the registration_ids) via Test Send on Azure's Notification Hub, but I'm getting a bad request error.

```
{
"registration_ids" : ["2670873167838193734-9582072870486547213-1"],
"data":{"message":"Hello World!"},
}
```

I'm not sure why since I checked the formatting and it looked fine to me based on other sources I saw.

Does anyone have an idea on what's happening?

**EDIT:**

Here's how I eventually managed to send a notification to a specific user:

on the client side (Java), I replaced the line

```
hub.register(regid)
```

with

```
hub.register(regid,"myTag")
```

Where "myTag" can be any other string tag you want. That way you can enter the word myTag in the 'Send to Tag' on Azure's Notification Hub and verify that you received the notification on your device.

Also, if you want to send the notification from the server side (C#), you'll need to add this header to your http request:

```
request.Headers.Add("ServiceBusNotification-Tags", "myTag");
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

registration_id would not be part of the payload (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223273.aspx request body) although it is part of GCM's payload. To send to a specific device, you will need to tag that device with an id of sorts (e.g. registration_ids) and send to the tag "{registration_id}".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain a bit more on how does one tag a device given the registration id 2670873167838193734-9582072870486547213-1?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to registration_ids field in the payload. Notification Hub does allow passing the registration_ids in the payload. Notification Hub internally substitute the registration id (before sending to GCM/FCM) based on selected devices.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx

Thanks,
Sateesh