# (400) BadRequest using Azure Notification Hub from an Azure Function when Test page is working

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I have Azure Notifications Hubs set up on iOS device and it is receiving messages from the Test Send page in Azure Notification Hubs, but I cannot seem to get an Azure Function Timer to send notifications using the backend adapted code examples for [specific devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-xplat-segmented-apns-push-notification) and [specific users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-ios-apple-apns-notification).

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) BadRequest. Reason: Bad Request..TrackingId:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx,TimeStamp:2024-03-26T10:35:00.5448540Z
```

The code is:

```
    private async Task sendMessageAsync() {

        _logger.LogInformation("SendingMessage...");

        
        NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient
                        .CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=<endpoint string>"
                        , "<hub name>");

        try {

            var msg = "\"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Notification Hub test notification\"}}";
            await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(msg);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }

    }
```

I copied the `DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature` from the Notification Hub and am using the right Notification Hub name. The test message itself is taken from the Notification Hub test page. I am sending from Azure Functions running on my MacOS using Visual Studio, but don't think that matters.

I am using this in the .csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs" Version="4.2.0" />
```

This post, [Getting Bad Request (400) on Azure Notification Hub's "Test Send"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919302/getting-bad-request-400-on-azure-notification-hubs-test-send), didn't apply as the test send is working. this post, [NotificationHub BadRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/745750/notificationhub-badrequest) didn't have a resolution. This post, [Azure Apple Push Notification Error: 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814066/azure-apple-push-notification-error-400-bad-request), the test was not working. This post, [azure-notificationhubs IOS Bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43629857/azure-notificationhubs-ios-bad-request), the test was not working.

These posts seem to use the same method:

- [Sending Push Notifications from a Azure Function](https://blog.verslu.is/azure/push-notifications-azure-function/)
- [Getting Started — Azure, Notification Hub, and iOS](https://medium.com/@Dbradford/getting-started-azure-notification-hub-and-ios-ea7ca648416a)
- [ASP .NET Core Web API with Azure Notification Hub](https://techmindfactory.com/ASP-.NET-Core-Web-API-with-Azure-Notification-Hub/)

**UPDATE**

I thought I might try a console app, to avoid all the local function complexity in case that was somehow the problem, but still received the 400 error.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace NotificationConsole;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        SendNotificationAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task SendNotificationAsync()
    {

        NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient
                    .CreateClientFromConnectionString("<endpoint connection string"
                    , "<hub name>");

        NotificationOutcome outcome = null;

        try {

            var msg = "\"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Notification Hub test notification\"}}";
            outcome = await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(msg,"");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

I followed this post, [Push notification does not send from console using Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745507/push-notification-does-not-send-from-console-using-azure), and the article in the answer, [Sending Notification From A Console Application Using Notification Hubs](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sending-notification-from-a-console-application-using-notification-hubs), which was a Windows push, but I just replaced the call and still it didn't work.